# How to replicate the Volume Up/Down keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut-keys, pulseaudio

I have a notebook with no dedicated (working) keys for volume, so I've set under the Shortcuts Settings to use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> to change volume. That's working fine and I get that nice popup showing the volume level when I press this shortcut.

But I've bought a keyboard with dedicated keys, and I want to be able to use BOTH. Thus, I would need to copy the initial shortcut... But I have no idea of what command the original shortcut fires. I've tried `amixer` command: it works, but there's no visual cue of the volume level.

Comment: what should i look for? this post is quite meaningless for me, and additionally, hald outputs "command not found" here

Comment: I'm very confused by your comment, @Igoru. Which post do you mean by "this post"? If you have something to add to your question, you can edit it.

Comment: forget about it. a random user added a comment saying "hey, look at this post that has a solution", and I replied that. After all, the guy removed his comment and my comment got meaningless.

Comment: I had a very similar issue, which I solved myself and decided to post in case it helped anyone else, so if you're using KDE you can try this: http://askubuntu.com/q/422078/11331. The first solution displays a volume level popup like you want, I'm sure there's a gnome equivalent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help with mapping my keyboard](http://askubuntu.com/questions/354422/need-help-with-mapping-my-keyboard)