# Need help with mapping my keyboard

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm learning how to use Ubuntu right now, so far I'm enjoying it. There is this one thing I don't understand. I want to replace my <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> button with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. If I want to use T only I know I should use

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 87 = t"
```

but I have no idea how to add the ALT button, any help.

Comment: please tell the brand

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/300203#300203) help?

Answer (score 2):

Discover how your system sees those keys, using the command `xev` and pressing the keys whose id you want to discover.After entering the `xev` just press page up and then press alt+t then you will get the following results. Then use the key code you got on pressing alt+t keys in the command at the end. that's all it will be done. I did this on my laptop and got the below results and so i gave it for reference only. You have to perform action to get your own result as these results vary with computer.

Pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> produces keycode 111, assigned to action `Up`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
root 0xa5, subw 0x0, time 13739005, (165,-16), root(170,32),
state 0x0, keycode 111 (keysym 0xff52, Up), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Pressing <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> key gives the following:

```
KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
root 0xc3, subw 0x0, time 13714833, (61,151), root:(63,236),
state 0x10, keycode 112 (keysym 0xff55, Prior), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Once you know the keycode of the keys you would like to use, and the name of the actions you want to perform, you can assign the desired actions to the chosen keys.
The following four commands will produce the desired change, valid only for the present X session:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 112 = Up"
```

To get these changes for every session, after issuing the commands above, create a file called .Xmodmap (or whatever), with the following command:

```
xmodmap -pke > .Xmodmap
```

Then, create a file called .xinitrc in your home directory, containing just the following line:

```
xmodmap .Xmodmap
```

Enjoy!

Refer to the site for any doubts: http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/...txkbmap_Method

Comment: The OP asked to replace `Pg Up` with `Alt+T`, not with `Up`. So, the answer will be nice if will show how can the sum of two keys to be replaced with only one. And the given link is broken.

Comment: Why did you changed `xmodmap -e "keycode 112 = Up"` to `xmodmap -e "keycode 112 = Prior"`? This is by default. See the output of `xmodmap -pke | grep Prior` command.

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake.There is no change in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a combination of keys using `xmodmap` to a keycode. So, you can't replace replace <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. If you do something like:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 112 = Alt_L+t"
```

you will get an error.

You can understand this and if you look at the output of the following command:

```
xmodmap -pke
```

---

But with some tricks, if you really want to replace <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, you can do it. You will need `xdotool` to do this. To install it run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Now, just for test, if you run the following command in terminal:

```
xdotool key Alt+t
```

you will see that this have the same behavior like when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. So, all you have to do now is to add <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> as a custum shortcut for this command. See here how you can create a custom keyboard shortcut: https://askubuntu.com/a/69161/147044.