# How do I control the volume in KDE from the command line?

Tags: kde, volume-control

I want to use xbindkeys to set a key combination to increase/decrease the volume, but to do that I need a command to run to change the volume, without having to click the volume icon and change it with the mouse. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `qdbus` to access the graphical kmix from the command line. These are the commands to increase and decrease the volume:

```
qdbus org.kde.kmix /kmix/KMixWindow/actions/increase_volume com.trolltech.Qt.QAction.trigger

qdbus org.kde.kmix /kmix/KMixWindow/actions/decrease_volume com.trolltech.Qt.QAction.trigger
```

for reference, `man qdbus`  shows the syntax is `qdbus <service> <path> <method> <args>`, and you can see a list of available options at each stage by running a shorter command - e.g, running `qdbus org.kde.kmix` will show a list of available paths, and `qdbus org.kde.kmix /kmix/KMixWindow/actions/decrease_volume` will show a list of available methods for that path, etc. Note that the methods marked as being read or readwrite can be called with no argument to get their current value - this may be useful to you for automation.

Alternatively, you can access the volume control directly - i.e. not via the graphical kmixer - with the /Mixers option.

Just call `qdbus org.kde.kmix /Mixers org.kde.KMix.MixSet.currentMasterControl` to find out the current master control (in my case, alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo). Then use the mixer matching that name, i.e. /Mixers/0/alsa_output_pci_0000_00_1b_0_analog_stereo, with the method org.kde.KMix.Control.increaseVolume or org.kde.KMix.Control.decreaseVolume.

So, the direct access to the volume control will be something like this:

```
qdbus org.kde.kmix /Mixers/0/alsa_output_pci_0000_00_1b_0_analog_stereo org.kde.KMix.Control.increaseVolume

qdbus org.kde.kmix /Mixers/0/alsa_output_pci_0000_00_1b_0_analog_stereo org.kde.KMix.Control.decreaseVolume
```

Which will change the volume, without doing anything graphical.

Comment: N1! Just a note: the qt argument changed, and now it is `org.qtproject.Qt.QAction.trigger`, i.e. to increase volume one ought to call `qdbus org.kde.kmix /kmix/KMixWindow/actions/decrease_volume org.qtproject.Qt.QAction.trigger`

Comment: I got `Service 'org.kde.kmix' does not exist.` when I tried this answer. The current solution in 2022 is `qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kmix invokeShortcut "decrease_volume"` to decrease the volume; replace `decrease_volume` with `increase_volume` or `mute` to do those actions.

Answer (score 0):

**Volume Increase**

```
qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kmix invokeShortcut increase_volume
```

**Volume Decrease**

```
qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kmix invokeShortcut decrease_volume
```

**Mute**

```
qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kmix invokeShortcut mute
```